# How to add clearfix class according to to the posts number?

Tags: php

Will be pleased for any help! The site is done on bootstrap.
I have 3 column site.
I want simply to add class clearfix if number of `posts % 3 == 0;`
I can add only through browser DevTools

I have my posts code as fallowing:

```
$pages = get_posts( array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'category'    => '20',
'orderby'     => 'ID',
'order'       => 'ASC',
'post_type'   => 'post',
));

foreach( $pages as $post ) 
    setup_postdata($post);
```

I'm doing this way but it doesn't work.

```
foreach( $pages as $post ) { 
if ($post[0] % 3 == 0) {
    setup_postdata($post.'<\div class="clearfix"\>');
}
else {
    setup_postdata($post);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your second code part with

```
$count = 1;

foreach( $pages as $post ) { 
  setup_postdata($post);

  // show your post here

  if ($count++ % 3 === 0)
    echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
```

Comment: IT WOOOOOOOOOOOORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Nice. Accept the answer, please :)

Comment: But it works only for !one section!:-((( If I have 3-5 sections with 3 columns it doesn't work! it inserts clearfix after the first column and than after the 4th <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="clearfix"></div> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"> <div class="clearfix">

Comment: I've updated my code and change start $count value. Try with it